# Javascript/CSS Is it possible to filter a certain color from a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, I have a picture of a black star on a white background.  I will be using jquery to make it so that the user can drag this star around.  However, how can I make it so that the white background color is technically transparent?  I don't want the image to be transparent- only the images white background color.  I want it to be transparent so the user can drag it over other colored divs without noticing that the background exists.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: make the image background transparent and set the background per css white!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not modify an image background (assuming it's not transparent) unless you are using something as SVG, that allows you to change things on what's drawn.

If it's transparent, setting a simple `background: #ff0000` (red) would change the transparent areas to that color, witch I don't like to use, but really works.

If you choose an SVG solution (that I understant would solve it and it's kinda not-so-hard), I'd recommend some library, such as [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) (that I personally preffer) or [Rafaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) (that gives support all the way back to IE6, what costs features to this awsome library)

Answer (score 1):

This is white set to fully transparent. The last value is the opacity. If you want 50% opacity for example, use `0.5`.

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
```